# mySQL get the next and previous dates to the date of the current row

Tags: mysql

I have table with a date column which I am using to query to get a set of rows back from.

I am not storing any time value just the date and T:00:00:00

I need to workout what is the next and previous days that I have data for.

I would love to be able to do a single Query and the dates to use the next and back UI nav with the Query to select the current data set

so  start with this to get the last set of data

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `newco_bh_price_data` 
WHERE  `manager_id` =960
AND  `currency_id` =0
AND  `class_id` =  'A'
AND  `price_date` 
IN (SELECT MAX(  `price_date` ) 
FROM  `newco_bh_price_data`
)
```

I now need to know what the next date will be so I can query on it

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `newco_bh_price_data` 
WHERE  `manager_id` =960
AND  `currency_id` =0
AND  `class_id` =  'A'
AND  `price_date` = '2002-09-19'
```

Mant thanks for any help and comments

Here is a sample of the data

```
id  price_date  manager_id  currency_id class_id    value   v_change
554 2002-09-19  960 0   A   8.631   0
553 2002-09-19  960 0   A   9.5635  0
552 2002-09-18  960 0   A   9.1068  0
551 2002-09-18  960 0   A   8.9351  0
550 2002-09-18  960 0   A   9.61    0
549 2002-09-17  960 0   A   9.1868  0
548 2002-09-17  960 0   A   9.0201  0
547 2002-09-17  960 0   A   9.6425  0
546 2002-09-16  960 0   A   9.3377  0
545 2002-09-16  960 0   A   9.3317  0
544 2002-09-16  960 0   A   9.6902  0
543 2002-09-13  960 0   A   9.418   0
542 2002-09-13  960 0   A   9.3669  0
541 2002-09-13  960 0   A   9.7125  0
540 2002-09-12  960 0   A   9.4463  0
539 2002-09-12  960 0   A   9.4383  0
538 2002-09-12  960 0   A   9.7474  0
537 2002-09-11  960 0   A   9.5303  0
536 2002-09-11  960 0   A   9.6592  0
535 2002-09-11  960 0   A   9.8041  0
534 2002-09-10  960 0   A   9.4666  0
533 2002-09-10  960 0   A   9.5878  0
532 2002-09-10  960 0   A   9.7651  0
531 2002-09-09  960 0   A   9.3104  0
530 2002-09-09  960 0   A   9.4841  0
529 2002-09-09  960 0   A   9.7498  0
528 2002-09-06  960 0   A   9.2462  0
527 2002-09-06  960 0   A   9.3823  0
526 2002-09-06  960 0   A   9.7501  0
525 2002-09-05  960 0   A   9.0465  0
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions that you really want are `lag()` and `lead()`.  But, alas, these are not available in MySQL.  I think the easiest way to implement them is using correlated subqueries.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT *,
       (select price_date
        from newco_bh_price_data pd1
        where pd1.manager_id = pd.manager_id and
              pd1.currency_id = pd.currency_id and
              pd1.class_id = pd.class_id and
              pd1.price_date > pd.price_date
        order by price_date
        limit 1
       ) as next_price_date,
       (select price_date
        from newco_bh_price_data pd1
        where pd1.manager_id = pd.manager_id and
              pd1.currency_id = pd.currency_id and
              pd1.class_id = pd.class_id and
              pd1.price_date < pd.price_date
        order by price_date desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_price_date
FROM  `newco_bh_price_data` pd
WHERE  `manager_id` =960
AND  `currency_id` =0
AND  `class_id` =  'A'
AND  `price_date` = '2002-09-19';
```

This assumes that you want manager, currency, and class to be the same when looking for the next and previous date.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e37ac/5)**

```
SELECT t1.*,
       (SELECT MIN(t2.`price_date`)
        FROM `newco_bh_price_data` t2
        WHERE t2.`price_date`> t1.`price_date`
        AND t2.`manager_id`= t1.`manager_id`
        AND t2.`currency_id` = t1.`currency_id`
        AND t2.`class_id` = t1.`class_id`
        ) AS NextDate,
       (SELECT MAX(t2.`price_date`)
        FROM `newco_bh_price_data` t2
        WHERE t2.`price_date`< t1.`price_date`
        AND t2.`manager_id`= t1.`manager_id`
        AND t2.`currency_id` = t1.`currency_id`
        AND t2.`class_id` = t1.`class_id`
        ) AS PreviousDate
FROM  `newco_bh_price_data` t1
WHERE  t1.`manager_id` =960
AND  t1.`currency_id` =0
AND  t1.`class_id` =  'A'
```

Result:

```
|  ID |                       PRICE_DATE | MANAGER_ID | CURRENCY_ID | CLASS_ID | VALUE | V_CHANGE |                         NEXTDATE |                     PREVIOUSDATE |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 554 | September, 19 2002 00:00:00+0000 |        960 |           0 |        A |     9 |        0 |                           (null) | September, 18 2002 00:00:00+0000 |
| 553 | September, 19 2002 00:00:00+0000 |        960 |           0 |        A |    10 |        0 |                           (null) | September, 18 2002 00:00:00+0000 |
| 552 | September, 18 2002 00:00:00+0000 |        960 |           0 |        A |     9 |        0 | September, 19 2002 00:00:00+0000 | September, 17 2002 00:00:00+0000 |
| 551 | September, 18 2002 00:00:00+0000 |        960 |           0 |        A |     9 |        0 | September, 19 2002 00:00:00+0000 | September, 17 2002 00:00:00+0000 |
| 550 | September, 18 2002 00:00:00+0000 |        960 |           0 |        A |    10 |        0 | September, 19 2002 00:00:00+0000 | September, 17 2002 00:00:00+0000 |
| 549 | September, 17 2002 00:00:00+0000 |        960 |           0 |        A |     9 |        0 | September, 18 2002 00:00:00+0000 | September, 16 2002 00:00:00+0000 |
| 548 | September, 17 2002 00:00:00+0000 |        960 |           0 |        A |     9 |        0 | September, 18 2002 00:00:00+0000 | September, 16 2002 00:00:00+0000 |
```